# Anyone want to meet in chat and play some online blitz?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Are there any players around who would like to meet in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3293/chess) and play some online blitz?

At some point we can potentially arrange a tournament with site users.

It will help new users see our site live, and it will be an interesting opportunity for users to play and improve.

Hope to see you in the [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3293/chess)!

Answer (score 1):

I think that we've got to arrange something on lichess.